# Animation running before Activity is visible

Tags: android, android-activity, android-animation

I am starting off some animations as soon as my Activity is created.

However, by the time the Activity is fully visible the animation has already half completed.

I originally had it in onCreate but have now moved in into onWindowFocusChanged and only start the activity once I know onResume has also been called (I'm setting a boolean in onResume)

Is there anyway of knowing when an Activity is fully visible? Or am I going to have to set a 1 second delay? (This seems extremely hacky and potentially still won't work on slower phones/tablets)

Comment: Did you found any solution for this problem? Even I am in the same situation. I want animate a view after the activity is completely visible to the user.

Comment: Sorry Nitesh but i don't think i ever did. I changed my project to using a game engine rather than normal android code in the end

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to display your animations to the user, one way you could guarantee they see the entire animation is by triggering it with an onClickListener() for the whole screen, and just wait for them to touch it?

Comment: But if they don't touch the screen, then the app will appear to have frozen until they touch the screen. That's not a great UI experience.

Comment: I certainly Agree. Maybe a Visual Queue to encourage them to touch the screen like 'touch here to begin', I only bring this up because I found myself in a similar situation recently and I used a triangle shaped play button. Attracts attention, doesn't look goofy, and draws attention to the screen so the user expects something to happen.

Answer (score 0):

for layout animations you can use LayoutAnimation, here is the link [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/LayoutAnimationController.html)

Comment: I'm using ViewPropertyAnimator. The animations are working fine, I just need to fire them after the screen has fully appeared.

Comment: okay, i can not say any thing if i dont see your code but you can set 100 milis like short time to delay your animation. may be it is a workaroud.

Answer (score 0):

As of API level 21, you can implement the [`Activity#onEnterAnimationComplete()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onEnterAnimationComplete()) callback. Unfortunately, it seems like there's no AppCompat equivalent at this point.